# Add flags after comparing columns of dates

Tags: sas

suppose to have the following data set.

> ```
>    ID       Hired       Start_date     End_date       Flag_Start     Flag_End
>   0001      1-1900      01JAN2018      21DEC2018           1             2 
>   0001      1-1900      01JAN2019      01DEC2020           2             2
>   0002      10-2020     26MAR2020      03MAY2020           1             2 
>   0003      03-2021     18DEC2020      31DEC2020           1             2
>  .....      .......     .........      .........      ...........   ...........
> ```

I would like the desired output. Sorry if I ask you but I'm a newbie and this seems to be a very difficult task with SAS. I'm familiar with R.

Desired output:

> ```
>    ID       Hired       Start_date     End_date       Flag_Start     Flag_End
>   0001      1-1900      01JAN2018      21DEC2018           1             2 
>   0001      1-1900      01JAN2019      01DEC2020           2             3
>   0002      03-2020     26MAR2020      03MAY2020           1             0 
>   0003      03-2021     18DEC2020      31DEC2020           1             3
>  .....      .......     .........      .........      ...........   ...........
> ```

So, for each ID, if, after sorting, the last End_date is "x" and the "Hired" is 1-1900 then in Flag_End add 3 otherwise if Hired is < End_date add 0 otherwise if Hired is > End_date but not 1-1900 add 3.

Thank you in advance

Comment: When you say *add 3* do you really mean assign the value `3`?  If the data shown is already in a data set, what is the `Hired` variable, character or numeric with a format? Is `1-1900` supposed to mean *missing* Hired date? (Zero (0) is the number corresponding to SAS date value 01-JAN-1900)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want.

The Hired Date does not match between your two posted data sets. I chose the second one (03-2020).

```
data have;
input ID $ Hired :anydtdte. (Start_date End_date)(:date9.) Flag_Start Flag_End;
format Hired Start_date End_date date9.;
datalines;
0001 1-1900  01JAN2018 21DEC2018 1 2 
0001 1-1900  01JAN2019 01DEC2020 2 2 
0002 03-2020 26MAR2020 03MAY2020 1 2 
0003 03-2021 18DEC2020 31DEC2020 1 2 
;

data want;
   set have;
   by ID;
      if last.ID then do;
           if Hired = '01jan1900'd then flag_end = 3;
      else if Hired <  End_date then flag_end = 0;
      else if Hired >= End_date then flag_end = 3;
   end;
run;
```